# How to use React Router on top of Rails router (not using react-rails gem)?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

Now i am making React app on top off Ruby on Rails app (with out react-rails gem) by using [browserify-rails](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails) to compile js files.

So i tried to us [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) to config router of the app

This is my main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM  from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

/*Import Component*/

import DashBoard from './components/dashboard';
import Group from './components/dashboard';

/*
 *
 * Routes
 *
 * */

var routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={DashBoard}/>
        <Route path="/group" component={Group}/>
    </Router>
);

ReactDOM.render(routes , document.querySelector('#main'));
```

But when i go to

```
http://my.app.dev/group
```

I got

```
No route matches [GET] "/group" (From Rails)
```

So how can i fix this and make React Router on top off Rails router?

Thanks!

Answer (score 54):

If you want to redirect all your request to single page, that's easy:

```
# config/routes.rb 

root 'dash_board#index'
get '*path', to: 'dash_board#index'
```

If Rails will render your React components on DashBoard#index page, React's router will intercept it from there.

Comment: Is this a good practice? Do you then make all actions non-html and handle all routing in react? Just trying to learn the purpose of react routing, thanks!

Comment: Having a "first level" wildcard route can deal to problems with some gems. What you could do is to mount your app, for instance in a namespace. For instance: https://yourdomain/a . It is uglier but safer.

Comment: Can such app be considered a real SPA?

Comment: @prograils It does not prevent it from being a SPA. It just handles the case where the user navigates to one of those URLs. The server does not get hit when React links are used to navigate between React routes.

Comment: But what happens to API routes? How we will be able to call API if we force all request to go to one particular page?

Comment: @KrupaSuthar Good question. Rails routes matches top down, so if you put the `*path` at the very end of your file the API endpoints will remain untouched.

Comment: @JosephCho What if I have API at `/projects` route and also having the react page with URL `/projects`?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly you can still have the `*path` at the end of the file. It's a catch all if none of the above routes matched.

Comment: This approach has a problem when you are dealing with URL generated when retrieving files from `ActiveStorage`. I get a 406 error (Not Acceptable). It seems that ActiveStorage is not taking control of this route anymore after the addition of the solution proposed here.

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify all the URLs you need in Router, manually in routes.rb, redirecting them to your rails controller with the Router, say /home:

```
# config/routes.rb 
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root action: :index, controller: 'home'

  get 'url1', action: :index, controller: 'home'
  get 'url2', action: :index, controller: 'home'
  get 'url3', action: :index, controller: 'home'
end
```

Note that your base React component will use Router to use the corresponding component, if you have something like:

```
<Route path="/url1" component={ ComponentForUrl1 } />
<Route path="/url2" component={ ComponentForUrl3 } />
<Route path="/url3" component={ ComponentForUrl2 } />
```

Comment: This still first sent the request to the rails router and then back to the react-router. Thus unloading the Root component.

Answer (score 0):

It might be 2 years later, but I believe I'm not the only one having this issue nowadays, so here's un updated answer that actually helped.

Instead of only defining a redirect from `*path`, to a desired route, a `constraints` parameter must be provided so requests for resources (css, js, etc.) don't get 406 responses:

```rb
get '*path', to: "home#index", constraints: ->(request) do
  !request.xhr? && request.format.html?
end
```

I found the solution [here](https://ligcreative.com/react-rails-api-part-3-router/).