# How to have Rails routes.rb redirect several paths to a single controller#action?

Tags: react-router, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm wondering if there is a way to use "resourceful routing" in Rails to have all the routes point to one controller#action. I want React Router to handle the links.

I've reviewed https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use and found this [How to use React Router on top of Rails router (not using react-rails gem)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491113/how-to-use-react-router-on-top-of-rails-router-not-using-react-rails-gem)

My current `routes.rb` file (is this the best way to achieve to do this?):

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root to: "home#index"

  get 'games', to: 'home#index'
  get 'games/new', to: 'home#index'
  get 'games/:id', to: 'home#index'
  get 'games/:id/edit', to: 'home#index'

  namespace :api do
    resources :games
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
  resources :games, controller: :home
```

This will provide you with the crud paths + index that you want. The paths will be

```rb
/games
/games/new
/games/:id
/games/:id/edit
```

all pointing to `HomeController`

And then you can still have you're namespaced routes

**UPDATE:**  Updated answer based on comment from op

Comment: Thank you!
To be clear, my code sample works, 

I'm using React to access the `/api/games/` API endpoint created in Rails. I'd like for `/games/` to be the entry point for HTML requests that React Router will handle from there. There are 2 sets of paths.
I'm just wondering if there's a way for `get [path] to: [controller#action]` statements to be cleaner (or "resourceful").

Comment: I'll update answer with what I think you're saying :D